# How to create a fixed top section without disruppting its elements?

Tags: html, css, fixed

I have added the `position: fixed;` to the top section where the menu and logo is placed. It did keep showing the menu while scrolling down but it also disrupted the order and space of the logo and menu.
Is there a way to overcome this issue? or and alternative way to keep the menu while scrolling down?

[The section that I want to keep while scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDBQh.png)

[The unwanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6nBS.png)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 3fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo . menu menu" "hi hi hi hi" "what what what what" "projects projects projects projects""contact contact contact contact";
}

.logo {
  background: #fafafa;
  grid-area: logo;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: menu;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.menu a+a {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
}

.menu a:hover::after {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.hi {
  grid-area: hi;
  background-color: #c2edda;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hi img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 37em;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  padding: 150px 150px 150px 50px;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  .hi {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .hi p {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .hi img {
    display: none;
  }
  .hi {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.hi p {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.what {
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  grid-area: what;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.what img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.projects {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  grid-area: projects;
  background-color: khaki;
}

.pContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". headline headline ." "p1 p2 p3 p4" ". . . .";
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headline {
  grid-area: headline;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p1 {
  grid-area: p1;
}

.p2 {
  grid-area: p2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p3 {
  grid-area: p3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p4 {
  grid-area: p4;
}

.contact {
  grid-area: contact;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <a href="#who" class="list-inline-item">Who</a>
      <a href="#skills" class="list-inline-item">What</a>
      <a href="#proj" class="list-inline-item">Projects</a>
      <a class="list-inline-item">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="who" class="hi">
    <img src="photo.png" alt="photo">
    <p id="para">
      
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="skills" class="what">
    <h1>Knowledge and Skills</h1>
    <img src="3logo.png">
  </div>

  <div id="proj" class="projects">


    <div class="pContainer">
      <div class="headline">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p1"></div>
      <div class="p2">Lone Soldier Realty</div>
      <div class="p3">Freelance Graphic Design</div>
      <div class="p4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="contact">


    </div>

  </div>
```

[GitHub Link to Website Code](https://github.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io)

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hi Avihyb. You should create a working example here on stackoverflow instead of linking to a github source where your code is. Spend a few moments and do that and it will help your changes to get help. I could easy see this question being closed soon if you don't do that. Thought I give you the heads up.

Comment: So make a copy of the whole html source and css?

Comment: In your case here I would say go for the full source and css. Other times you could just pick the relevant elements and css, like you don't have to include a footer and content part if that is not affected by the error.

Comment: Added. Thank you very much Dejan, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For this `position: sticky` is good.

What i did is wrapped your logo and the links into 1 div with `display:flex`

Then i moved it out of the grid area at the top and gave it `position: sticky: top: 0;`

That means your element will be first relative. If the element reaches `top: 0` it will stick to it

Little note here: Usually we set reset the margin, padding and box-sizing at the top.

like:

```
html {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 3fr 3fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo . menu menu" "hi hi hi hi" "what what what what" "projects projects projects projects""contact contact contact contact";
}

.logo {
  background: #fafafa;
  grid-area: logo;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: menu;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.menu a+a {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
}

.menu a:hover::after {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.hi {
  grid-area: hi;
  background-color: #c2edda;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hi img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 37em;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  padding: 150px 150px 150px 50px;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  .hi {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .hi p {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .hi img {
    display: none;
  }
  .hi {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.hi p {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.what {
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  grid-area: what;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.what img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.projects {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  grid-area: projects;
  background-color: khaki;
}

.pContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". headline headline ." "p1 p2 p3 p4" ". . . .";
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headline {
  grid-area: headline;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p1 {
  grid-area: p1;
}

.p2 {
  grid-area: p2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p3 {
  grid-area: p3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p4 {
  grid-area: p4;
}

.contact {
  grid-area: contact;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.stickybar {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   background: #fafafa;
   padding: 0 10px;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="stickybar">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io/master/LOGO.png"></div>
     <div class="menu">
       <ul>
         <a href="#who" class="list-inline-item">Who</a>
         <a href="#skills" class="list-inline-item">What</a>
         <a href="#proj" class="list-inline-item">Projects</a>
         <a class="list-inline-item">Contact</a>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
<div class="grid-container">

  <div id="who" class="hi">
    <img src="photo.png" alt="photo">
    <p id="para">
      Hi! I'm Avichai, <br> I'm a 22 y/o junior web developer and designer. <br> My knowledge is based mainly <br> on my high school computer science extension, <br> my continuous self-learning and curisity.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="skills" class="what">
    <h1>Knowledge and Skills</h1>
    <img src="3logo.png">
  </div>

  <div id="proj" class="projects">


    <div class="pContainer">
      <div class="headline">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p1"></div>
      <div class="p2">Lone Soldier Realty</div>
      <div class="p3">Freelance Graphic Design</div>
      <div class="p4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="contact">


    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You might also want to include `z-index` to stop the image overlapping

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you.

You have to put both logo and menu in one wrapper so in our case header is the best match for wrapper and then add position fixed on that wrapper.

Put position fixed on header wrapper instead of menu and logo.

Also, I have added display flex on header and make it space between and align center.

```css
 html{
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
      background: #fafafa;  
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 3fr 3fr 2fr;
        
    grid-template-areas: "logo . menu menu" "hi hi hi hi" "what what what what" "projects projects projects projects""contact contact contact contact" ;
  }
  
  .logo { 
        background: #fafafa;
        grid-area: logo; 

        }
  
        .logo img{

            object-fit: contain;
        }
header.header{
          position: fixed;
          left:0;
          right:0; 
              display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:10px;
       background:#fafafa;
    }
  .menu { 
          
          grid-area: menu; 
          background-color: #fafafa;
        

          
          
        }
        .menu a{
              position: relative;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-size:20px;
              font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
              text-decoration: none;
              color: black;
            }

      .menu a + a{
            margin-left: 1rem;
      }
      .menu a::after{
            content:"";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2px;
            transform: scaleX(0);
            transition: transform 0.4s ease;
            transform-origin: bottom right;
            background-color: #ff9c00;

      }
  
      .menu a:hover::after{
            transform-origin: bottom left;
            transform: scaleX(1);
      }
  .hi { 
        grid-area: hi;
        background-color: #c2edda;
        height:100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        
      }

      .hi img{
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 37em;
            animation: fadein 2s;
            padding:150px 150px 150px 50px ;
      }
      @keyframes fadein {
            from { opacity: 0; }
            to   { opacity: 1; }
        }

      @media screen and (max-width: 1080px)
      {
            .hi{justify-content: flex-end;}
            .hi p{font-size: 20px !important;}
            
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 870px)
      {
            .hi img{display: none;}
            .hi{justify-content: center;}
      }
  
      .hi p{
            font-size: 35px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto';
      }
  .what {
      padding:50px 50px 50px 50px ;

         font-family: 'Roboto';
         grid-area: what;
         background-color: #fafafa;
         display: flex;
         justify-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         
        }   
        .what img{
              object-fit: contain;
              width: 15%;
              height: auto;
              position: absolute;
              margin-top: 100px;
        }
  
        .projects{
            font-family: 'Roboto';
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              padding: 50px 50px;
              grid-area: projects;
              background-color: khaki;
        }

        .pContainer{

            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            gap: 1px 1px;
            grid-template-areas:
              ". headline headline ."
              "p1 p2 p3 p4"
              ". . . .";
              justify-content: space-between;
        }

      .headline { grid-area: headline;
      display: flex;
justify-content: center; }

      .p1 { grid-area: p1; }

      .p2 { grid-area: p2;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;  }

      .p3 { grid-area: p3;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
             }

      .p4 { grid-area: p4; }


  .contact { 
         grid-area: contact;
         background-color: steelblue;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Avichai</title>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');
      </style> 
      <link rel="icon" href="logo.png" >
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
   <div class="grid-container">
   <header class="header">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io/master/LOGO.png" class="img-fluid" width="180" height="82"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <a href="#who" class="list-inline-item">Who</a>
      <a href="#skills" class="list-inline-item">What</a>
      <a href="#proj" class="list-inline-item">Projects</a>
      <a class="list-inline-item">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
  <div id="who" class="hi">
    <img src="photo.png" alt="photo" />
    <p id="para">
      Hi! I'm Avichai, <br>
      I'm a 22 y/o junior web developer and designer. <br>
      My knowledge is based mainly <br> on my high school computer science extension, <br>
      my continuous self-learning and curisity.
    </p>
  </div>
    <div id="skills" class="what"><h1>Knowledge and Skills</h1>
      <img src="3logo.png">
  </div>

  <div id="proj" class="projects">
    
    
    <div class="pContainer">
      <div class="headline"><h1>Projects</h1></div>
      <div class="p1"></div>
      <div class="p2">Lone Soldier Realty</div>
      <div class="p3">Freelance Graphic Design</div>
      <div class="p4"></div>
    </div>
  <div id="contact"class="contact">


  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what did you do and explain why?

Comment: Haha, awesome. I'll try to figure out from the code what's changed. But can you give a general brief on your solution?

Comment: hello @Dejan.S  sorry for inconvenience. I was writing my explanation meanwhile you have commented.

Comment: hello @avihyb sorry for inconvenience. I have given brief.

Comment: @avihyb There's a bit more to it as well. You'll want to study all of the settings for `display` in Prakash's answer.

Comment: I happened to like your solution. Even though it still keeps the logo and menu not positioned correctly, is it now a matter of margins? Or is there a smarter solution?

Answer (score -1):

First of all i added a div as **navbar** within **logo and menu**.

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io/master/LOGO.png"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <a href="#who" class="list-inline-item">Who</a>
        <a href="#skills" class="list-inline-item">What</a>
        <a href="#proj" class="list-inline-item">Projects</a>
        <a class="list-inline-item">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Because you fixed both logo and menu it changes to only fixed navbar that is inside them.
then added background color to navbar;

```
.navbar{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:9999; // for images overlaying the navbar.
}
```

then add `width:20%;` to logo also a width

```
.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width:20%;
}
```

and `width:75%;` and `margin-right:5%;` to menu

```
.menu {
  width:75%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
```

**Try the demo**.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 3fr 3fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo . menu menu" "hi hi hi hi" "what what what what" "projects projects projects projects""contact contact contact contact";
}

.logo {
  background: #fafafa;
  grid-area: logo;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  width:25%;
}

.logo img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: menu;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:104px;
  width:75%;

}
.navbar{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:9999;
}
.menu a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.menu a+a {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
}

.menu a:hover::after {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.hi {
  grid-area: hi;
  background-color: #c2edda;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hi img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 37em;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  padding: 150px 150px 150px 50px;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  .hi {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .hi p {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .hi img {
    display: none;
  }
  .hi {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.hi p {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.what {
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  grid-area: what;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.what img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.projects {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  grid-area: projects;
  background-color: khaki;
}

.pContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". headline headline ." "p1 p2 p3 p4" ". . . .";
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headline {
  grid-area: headline;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p1 {
  grid-area: p1;
}

.p2 {
  grid-area: p2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p3 {
  grid-area: p3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.p4 {
  grid-area: p4;
}

.contact {
  grid-area: contact;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io/master/LOGO.png"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <a href="#who" class="list-inline-item">Who</a>
        <a href="#skills" class="list-inline-item">What</a>
        <a href="#proj" class="list-inline-item">Projects</a>
        <a class="list-inline-item">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="who" class="hi">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io/master/photo.png" alt="photo">
    <p id="para">
      Hi! I'm Avichai, <br> I'm a 22 y/o junior web developer and designer. <br> My knowledge is based mainly <br> on my high school computer science extension, <br> my continuous self-learning and curisity.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="skills" class="what">
    <h1>Knowledge and Skills</h1>
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avihyb/avihyb.github.io/master/3logo.png">
  </div>

  <div id="proj" class="projects">


    <div class="pContainer">
      <div class="headline">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p1"></div>
      <div class="p2">Lone Soldier Realty</div>
      <div class="p3">Freelance Graphic Design</div>
      <div class="p4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="contact">


    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I overcome the overlapping issue with z-index? Do I give the menu a very big value so it will be ontop of everything?

Comment: That makes a high value :) for overflowing anything so silly man:)